# Design pattern for a data parsing&feature engineering pipeline

Tags: python, parsing, machine-learning, design-patterns, pipeline

I know this question has been asked a few times on these boards in the past, but I have a more generic version of it, which might be applicable to someone else's projects in the future as well.

In short - I am building an ML system (with Python, but language choice in this case is not very critical), which has its ML model at the end of a pipeline of actions happening:

- Data upload
- Data parsing
- Feature engineering
- Feature engineering (in a different logical bracket from prev. step)
- Feature engineering (in a different logical bracket from prev. steps)

... (more steps like the last 3)

- Data passed to ML model

Each of the above steps, has its own series of actions it must take, in order to build a proper output, which is then used as an input in the next one etc. These sub-steps in turn, can either be completely decoupled from one another, or some of them might need some steps inside of that big step, to be completed first, to produce data these following steps use.
The thing right now is, that I need to build a custom pipeline, which will make it super easy to add new steps into the mix (both big and small), without upsetting the existing ones.

So far, I have this concept idea of how this might look like from an architecture perspective, as shown below:

[image: Architecture concept]

While looking at this architecture, I am immediately thinking about a Chain of Responsibility Design Pattern, which manages BIG STEPS (1, 2, ..., n), and each of these BIG STEPS having their own small version of Chain of Responsibility happening inside of their guts, which happen independently for NO_REQ steps, and then for REQ steps (with REQ steps looping-over until they are all done). With a shared interface for running logic inside of big and small steps, it would probably run rather neatly.

Yet, I am wondering, if there is any better way of doing it? Moreover, what I do not like about a Chain of Responsibility, is that it would require a person adding new BIG/SMALL step, to always edit the "guts" of the logic setting up step bags, to manually include the newly added step. I would love to build something, which instead would just scan a folder specific to steps under each BIG STEP, and build a list of NO_REQ and REQ steps on its own (to uphold the Open/Closed SOLID principle).

I would be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: How did you get on with this? Would be very interested to hear if you developed a solution...

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar recently. Challenge is to allow "steps" to be plugged in easily without much changes. So, what I did was, something like below. Core idea is to define interface 'process' and fix input and output format.

[image]

**Code:**

```
class Factory:
    def process(self, input):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Extract(Factory):
    def process(self, input):
        print("Extracting...")
        output = {}
        return output

class Parse(Factory):
    def process(self, input):
        print("Parsing...")
        output = {}
        return output

class Load(Factory):
    def process(self, input):
        print("Loading...")
        output = {}
        return output

pipeline = {
    "Extract" : Extract(),
    "Parse" : Parse(),
    "Load" : Load(),
}

input_data = {} #vanilla input
for process_name, process_instance in pipeline.items():
    output = process_instance.process(input_data)
    input_data = output
```

**Output:**

```
Extracting...
Parsing...
Loading...
```

So, in case you need to add a 'step', 'append_headers' after parse, all you need to do is,

```
#Defining a new step.
class AppendHeaders(Factory):
    def process(self, input):
        print("adding headers...")
        output = {}
        return output

pipeline = {
    "Extract" : Extract(),
    "Append headers": AppendHeaders(), #adding a new step
    "Parse" : Parse(),
    "Load" : Load(),
}
```

**New output:**

```
Extracting...
adding headers...
Parsing...
Loading...
```

Additional requirement in your case where, you might want to scan specific folder for REQ/NOT_REQ, can be added as field in json and load it into pipeline, meaning, create those "steps" objects only if flag is set to REQ.

Not sure how much this idea can help. Thought, I will convey my thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply drd, but it does not address my concerns about breaking Open/Close principle when adding new small steps. Shared interface for process() method among big/small steps surely makes adding new steps less of a hassle, but it will still require me e.g. to revise big step's logic, when adding new small steps into it, and CoR's logic, when adding a new BIG step into it.